# World of Warcraft: Getting a value from a options/profile table so i can set functions

Tags: lua, lua-table, world-of-warcraft

```
core.defaults = {
    profile = {
        someInput = " ",
        someSelect = 1,
        general = {
                Blizzard = "Blizzard",
                Dark = "Dark",
                Class = "Class",
                Custom = "Custom"
        },
```

thats my settings but when i try and call something like

```
if core.db.profile.general == "Dark" then
   color = (0, 0, 0, 1)
end
```

it wont return "Dark" so when it tries to call for the color i get error

Ive tried making different tables even tried making a seperate toggle option for each theme, but i couldnt figure out how to make a toggle not active on the other options when one is checked like the image shows both options are ticked i couldnt figure out how to make it make one not active when the other is pressed.

[image: 1]

Comment: Your path is `core.defaults.profile.general.Dark`, but you are using `db` instead of defaults and not including `Dark` or are you creating an instance?